# How to save an image created from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, save

I want to save an image created from a numpy arry using plt.savefig(), but it failed. And my image is blank.My code is as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(10000).reshape((100,100))
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 300)
plt.imshow(array)
```

And how to add a colorbar to my image? Thank you very much.
Just like the below image.
[image]

Comment: What sort of image are you trying to create?

Comment: You did not create any figure (use plt.plot() for that). http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: @Nick Hale Like remote sensing image.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))

data = np.arange(10000).reshape((100,100))
plt.subplot(111)
plt.imshow(data,interpolation='nearest', cmap='bone', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(shrink=.92)

plt.savefig('imshow_ex.png', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

The above code can solve my problem.Thanks.